# How to use Arduino Uno as PS/2 to USB converter for typical keyboard usages?

Tags: arduino-uno, keyboard

I'm beginner in Arduino and recently programmed an Arduino uno board with various PS/2 to USB converters. They work when typing in Serial Monitor of Arduino IDE, but not in the other programs such as Notepad.

[image]

How can I connect the board as HID keyboard for usual works with my PS/2 keyboard?

**Update:**

As @KIIV mentioned in the comments, Uno hasn't native USB and his suggestion is to start with boards such as Leonardo.

I want to ask, what is the straightforward way of using Uno for this purpose?

Comment: Start with board with native USB and not UNO with USB-to-serial on different chip. Arduino leonardo for example

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

Comment: Thank you @KIIV, great answer! I googled your guide and found that some types of Arduino haven't built-in USB communication. As new question, is any way to work with Uno, as well?

Comment: Thank you @jsotola for your hint about site's laws, I'm not so familiar with them. The question and its text has been edited.

Comment: I thought I answered this question.  Oh, I did... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76755556/my-arduino-uno-ps-2-to-usb-works-only-in-serial-monitor-not-in-other-windows-app

Comment: I appreciate you @Delta_G, I sent a comment to your answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Uno has no generic USB module, it generally works only as a virtual serial device. Without additional hardware you cannot make a Uno work as a USB keyboard. In principle.

A possible solution is the usage of [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html). This nice library uses [bit-banging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging) to realize low-speed USB communication. A USB keyboard commonly is such a low-speed USB device.

Another possible solution is an accompanying software "driver" on the PC. It will receive the key events via the USB serial port and translate them to key events for the operating system. But I'm sure you will not want this.

Comment: I learned new things from your answer, @the busybee. Thanks.

Comment: @Khabarkhaan You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works. For example, you are not supposed to comment "thanks!" but to mark an answer as accepted. This is the best way to help future visitors on the same issue.